# TypeError openid yadis manager is not JSON serializable Django 1.6 and AllAuth

Tags: python, django

I have a web app that I'm trying to push to a EC2 box. This application works in debug on my local system, but I get the following error when it's on the cloud box.

http://dpaste.com/1566716/

```
TypeError at /accounts/openid/login/
<openid.yadis.manager.YadisServiceManager object at 0x7f8a75202510> is not JSON serializable
```

This seems to be the same issue as this post:
[django_openid_auth TypeError openid.yadis.manager.YadisServiceManager object is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301338/django-openid-auth-typeerror-openid-yadis-manager-yadisservicemanager-object-is)

But I added the line to the setting.py file to use Pickle as the default serializer, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'
```

I am at a loss. I made sure I have matching versions on my dev machine and on the cloud box, but it still doesn't work.

Anyone else have an idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I played around with this for hours. It finally dawned on me to restart Apache

```
service apache2 restart
```

After I did that, the SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer' line in the settings.py file seemed to take.